# How to make photo popup like Instagram with React-native

Tags: react-native

If you click a photo in Instagram without move off of the screen,
The photo pops up.
How can make this in React Native?
I read Navigator, but I guess it is not for that.
Could you recommend some tutorial or some documents about this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: I've implemented 'animated function changed by button' so far. But I think it's not for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use this [react-native-popup-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-dialog) as it seems you are beginner. Simply install package and then import popup component as documentation says. Some adjustments and effect is going to be almost same!